# how do i change content based on position of mouse over an image?

Tags: image, maps, hover

I have a picture of Country Norway : https://autopower.no/images/geoLocation/NO-578.png
As you can see - sort of - the image is devided into counties.

When the user hover over the county names on the left side - The image switches between 20 equal images with the corresponding county highlighted along with some information on the right side : https://autopower.no/?Page=Dealers

What I would like to do, is to have the exact same thing happen (to the content on the right) when the user hover over the image itself based on which county they hovering over.

I looked into some CSS image map, but I didn't get how I could use it in my case...

Could someone help me out by giving me some tips to what I should look into? how to get started or tell me if this is not possible with what I have set up so far - if I need/should use a different approach?

*I'm familiar with jQuery to some extent.*
*Was hoping not to use Flash.*

Answer (score 0):

You could use the .mouseover() and mouseout() jQuery methods to accomplish this, for example:

```
$(".county").mouseover(function() {
    var elementId = "#text-" + $(this).attr("id").split("-")[1];
    $(elementId).removeClass("hidden");
});

$(".county").mouseout(function() {
    var elementId = "#text-" + $(this).attr("id").split("-")[1];
    $(elementId).addClass("hidden");
});
```

I've built a simple fiddle demonstrating the use of this: http://jsfiddle.net/X2u2y/

Full documentation for this is available on the jQuery API site: http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

**EDIT:**

I can see what you're wanting here is to use a single graphic, with *hoverable* regions (an image map).  In order to do this, unfortunately you'll have to work out the coordinates for each *hoverable* region, and compose a map element consisting of areas, in the format:

```
<map name="parts">  
  <area shape="rect" coords="20,6,200,60" text-ref="county1">  
  <area shape="rect" coords="100,200,50" text-ref="county2">  
</map>
```

You should then be able to link each of those areas to a distinct jQuery mouseover event to accomplish what you need.  I've created another fiddle to get you started - apologies for going the long way round on this!

http://jsfiddle.net/jcAe9/

Comment: Either I misunderstood your answer, or you misunderstood my question. Anyway; What I need to accomplish,  is to know where the mouse cursor is on the picture. And based on where the cursor is, I can present the user the correct information on the right side. The same way I do when the user hover over the list of counties on the left side. Also have the map change so the county the user hover over is highlighted...

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a worked example of the kind of thing I think you're wanting - hopefully that helps!